# How to extract html paragraph elements only if they contain bold elements

Tags: python, html, wikipedia

I am trying to extract paragraph elements from a Wikipedia page, under the ID = 'See', all into a list.

Using :

```
import bs4
import requests


response = requests.get("https://wikitravel.org/en/Bhopal")

if response is not None:
    html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

`plot = []`

```
# find the node with id of "Plot"
mark = html.find(id="See")

# walk through the siblings of the parent (H2) node 
# until we reach the next H2 node
for elt in mark.parent.nextSiblingGenerator():
    if elt.name == "h2":
        break
    if hasattr(elt, "text"):
        plot.append(elt.text)
```

Now I want to be extracting only the paragraphs which contain a bold element inside them, How can I achieve this here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
I added few lines to your code. I have used lxml parser.(html is fine as well).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
import lxml
import ssl
import requests
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url = 'https://wikitravel.org/en/Bhopal'
content = requests.get('https://wikitravel.org/en/Bhopal').text
soup = bs(content, 'lxml')

plot =[]
mark = soup.find(id="See")

# # # walk through the siblings of the parent (H2) node 
# # # until we reach the next H2 node
for elt in mark.parent.next_siblings:
    if elt.name == "h2":
        break
    if hasattr(elt, "text") and (elt.find('b')):
        plot.append(elt.text)
print(*plot,sep=('\n')) #Just to print the list in a readable way
```

First few lines of the output on my jupyter notebook:

[image]